# MySQL connection over SSH tunnel - how to specify other MySQL server?

Tags: mysql, ssh-tunnel

I've got ~50 databases all set up at different host names, with the requirement that I connect to them through an SSH tunnel.

For example:

- SSH host at `ssh.example.com`
- MySQL host at `mysql1.example.com`

I have managed to create the tunnel using autossh (web server running Debian), but I can't seem to figure out how to connect to a specific MySQL hostname "beyond" the SSH tunnel.

Typing `lsof -i -n | egrep '\<ssh\>'` confirms that the tunnel is working (sends port 3307 to ssh.example.com port 3306)

So when I try `mysql -h 127.0.0.1 -P 3307` I get Connection refused. Not too weird since it's not an MySQL server.

My question to you guys:

How do I specify the `mysql1.example.com` host AFTER creating the SSH tunnel? I've tried searching everywhere but can't seem to figure it out.

Comment: I'm not familiar with 'autossh', but if you have a working ssh-tunnel you are using, i'd say just replace `127.0.0.1` with the actual target?

Comment: @Nanne, thank you for your comment. However 127.0.0.1 is required to tigger the tunnel, otherwise it'll just try to connect directly to the remote host.

Answer (score 147, accepted):

Solved it! The thing was to connect to the correct server when creating the tunnel itself - should've seen that one coming.

`ssh -f user@ssh.example.com -L 3307:mysql1.example.com:3306 -N`

Then `mysql -h 127.0.0.1 -P 3307` worked as intended. :)

Comment: what's the `-N` option for?

Comment: @abbood the -N option is to only create the tunnel, nothing more after that.

Comment: More specifically, you need to specify the address to which the mysql server is bound to. Look up bind-address in your my.cnf file. That's what goes between the two colon separators.

Comment: Just a note: it is important to use `127.0.0.1` in the `mysql` command because if you use `localhost` the `P` param will be ignored. It took me some headaches to figure out this.

Comment: Thanks ! All the documentation I saw let me think that you couldn't, and that Mysql Workbench wasn't using such an ssh tunnel. You (almost) saved my life

Comment: You can also use `--protocol=tcp` when connecting with the mysql client. So the command would look like so `mysql -P 3307 --protocol=tcp`

Comment: If we assume your example, in my case, when I wrote `mysql -h 127.0.0.1 -P 3307 -u user -p`, it says `Access denied for user 'user'@'ssh.example.com'`. It tries to connect `ssh.example.com` instead of `mysql1.example.com`

Comment: Okey I've solved it. The password was wrong. `'user'@'ssh.example.com'` part of the error confused me. I thought that it was trying to connect to the db on `ssh.example.com`.

Comment: This is just what I was looking for, quick question - how do i close the tunnel?

Comment: @MattTheNinja First run `ps aux | grep 3306` and then kill the process ID (pid) with `kill -9 (pid)`

Comment: If MySQL server is the same as the SSH host, `ssh user@ssh.example.com -L 3307:localhost:3306` to open a shell (`exit` manually or automatically when connection is closed, save the hassle to run `ps aux` and `kill` later) and on local run `mysql -P 3307 --protocol=tcp` or `mysql -P 3307 -h 127.0.0.1` as @fguillen pointed out `-P` is ignored when `-h localhost`

Answer (score 20):

When you don't have direct access to `mysql-server`, you use `jump-server`.

From your machine, you connect(ssh) to jump-server and from there you connect to your `mysql-server`.

This can be avoided by using `ssh- tunneling`.

Suppose your

```
       jump server is `jump-ip`
       mysql server is `mysql-ip`
       your machine is `machine-ip`
```

Just open ssh client(Putty in windows or terminal in linux/ios).

Type:

```
    ssh -L [local-port]:[mysql-ip]:[mysql-port] [jump-server-user]@[jump-ip]
```

After this, you can use your `localhost` and `local-port` to access mysql-server on the remote machine directly.

Eg. Your Jdbc url to access mysql database, in that case, will be

```
jdbc:mysql://localhost:[local-port]/[database-name]
```

**For Windows Users, Using Putty to connect to remote MySQL Server via Tunneling**

Step1: Enter your Jump server Host/IP in the session tab
[image: Step1]

Step2: Go to `SSH` tab--> `Tunnels`: Enter Your MySQL server HostName: Port as destination and Source port as your local port where you want to tunnel that service and click on `Add`
[image: Step2]

Step3: Go back to Session tab and click on `Open` and Enter your credentials, if it is Username/Password based.

And use same credential as mentioned above:

```
jdbc:mysql://localhost:[local-port]/[database-name]
```

Answer (score 16):

I got a nice blog about how to connect to MySQL using SSH tunnel. It is very well explained [here](https://web.archive.org/web/20160613004918/http://blog.webyog.com/2012/09/12/how-to-integrating-ssh-tunneling-inside-your-application/).

The command to connect to SSH tunnel:

```
ssh -L [listening port]:[REMOTE_MYSQL_HOST]:[REMOTE_MYSQL_PORT] [SSH_USER]@[SSH_HOST]
```

The command to connect to MySQL:

```
localhost:[listening port]
```

Comment: this is a dead link

Comment: Had to add -N parameter before -L

Answer (score 6):

I created a tunnelto the DB using this command

```
ssh  -L 10000:localhost:3306  user@<ip addess to connect DB> -N -f
```

-L is local host port it is user defined u can provide any port number

between 0 to 65535. 0 to 1023 are reserved.

whether you are using key based authentication to the server you should

mention the key like this.

```
ssh -i <path of the private key>  -L 10000:localhost:3306  user@<ip addess to connect DB> -N -f
```