# SQLAlchemy through Paramiko SSH

Tags: python, mysql, ssh, sqlalchemy, paramiko

I have a database on a server which I need to access through SSH. Right now I deal with the DB by using the command line to get the data.

```
import paramiko
ssh = paramiko.SSHClient()
ssh.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
ssh.connect(hostname='XX.XX.XX', username='user', password='pass', port = YYY)
query = "mysql -u " + username_sql + " -p" + password_sql +" dbb -e \"" + sql_query + "\""
ssh.exec_command(query.decode('string_escape'))
ssh.close()
```

Is there a way to do this with SQLAlchemy to be more efficient and so I can work with pandas DataFrames directly?

```
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
engine = create_engine(
       "mysql://username_sql:password_sql@localhost/dbb")
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The easiest way to do this would be to run an SSH tunnel to the mysql port on the remote host. [For example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18374012):

```
ssh -f user@XX.XX.XX.XX -L 3307:mysql1.example.com:3306 -N
```

Then connect locally with SQLAlchemy:

```
engine = create_engine("mysql://username_sql:password_sql@localhost:3307/dbb")
```

If you really want to use paramiko, try [this demo code in the paramiko repo](https://github.com/paramiko/paramiko/blob/master/demos/forward.py#L54) or the [sshtunnel](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/sshtunnel/0.0.1) module. The `ssh` command might be the easiest method though.. and you can use [autossh](http://www.harding.motd.ca/autossh/) to restart the tunnel if it goes down.

Answer (score 21):

In case there is anyone who's interested in connecting to a remote **Postgresql** database via SSH and wants to load data into a **pandas DataFrame** here is how to do it.

Suppose we have installed a postgresql database on a remote server, to which we can ssh by the following parameters.

**SSH parameters:**

- Server's ip: `10.0.0.101`
- SSH port: `22` (*default port for SSH*)
- Username: `my_username`
- Password: `my_password`

**Database parameters:**

- Port: `5432` (*postgresql default port*)
- Database name: `db`
- Database user: `postgres_user` (*default username is `postgres`*)
- Database password: `postgres_pswd` (*default password is an empty string*)
- Table with our data: `MY_TABLE`

Now, we want to connect to this database on our end and load data into a pandas DataFrame:

```
from sshtunnel import SSHTunnelForwarder
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
import pandas as pd

server = SSHTunnelForwarder(
    ('10.0.0.101', 22),
    ssh_username="my_username",
    ssh_password="my_password",
    remote_bind_address=('127.0.0.1', 5432)
    )

server.start()
local_port = str(server.local_bind_port)
engine = create_engine('postgresql://{}:{}@{}:{}/{}'.format("postgres_user", "postgres_pswd", "127.0.0.1", local_port, "db"))

dataDF = pd.read_sql("SELECT * FROM \"{}\";".format("MY_TABLE"), engine)

server.stop()
```

Answer (score 8):

Just swap the (host, port) of the server with postgres:

```
from sshtunnel import SSHTunnelForwarder #Run pip install sshtunnel

server = SSHTunnelForwarder(
    (<'your host'>, <host port>),
    ssh_username=<"os remote username">,
    ssh_pkey=<'path/to/key.pem'>,  # or ssh_password.
    remote_bind_address=(<'postgres db host'>, <'postgres db port'>))

server.start()

connection_data = 'postgresql://{user}:{password}@{host}:{port}/{db}'.format(user=<'postgres user'>,
                                                                             password=<'postgres password'>,
                                                                             host=server.local_bind_host,
                                                                             port=server.local_bind_port,
                                                                             db=<'postgres db name'>)

engine = create_engine(connection_data)

# Do your queries

server.stop()
```

Answer (score 7):

You could use the SSHTunnel library as follows:

```
from sshtunnel import SSHTunnelForwarder #Run pip install sshtunnel
from sqlalchemy.orm import sessionmaker #Run pip install sqlalchemy

with SSHTunnelForwarder(
    ('10.160.1.24', 22), #Remote server IP and SSH port
    ssh_username = "<usr>",
    ssh_password = "<pwd>",
    remote_bind_address=('127.0.0.1', 5432)
    ) as server:

    server.start() #start ssh sever
    print 'Server connected via SSH'

    #connect to PostgreSQL
    local_port = str(server.local_bind_port)
    engine = create_engine('postgresql://<db_user>:<db_pwd>@127.0.0.1:' + local_port +'/<db_name>')

    Session = sessionmaker(bind=engine)
    session = Session()

    print 'Database session created'

    #test data retrieval
    test = session.execute("SELECT * FROM <table_name>")
```

Answer (score 3):

I'm going to piggy back @Matin Kh with a non-postgresql db - MySQL and using Pythonanywhere.com.
This code will take a table and convert it to an excel file.

```
import sshtunnel
import sqlalchemy
import pymysql
import pandas as pd
from pandas import ExcelWriter
import datetime as dt
from sshtunnel import SSHTunnelForwarder

server = SSHTunnelForwarder(
    ('ssh.pythonanywhere.com'),
    ssh_username='username', 
    ssh_password='password',
    remote_bind_address=('username.mysql.pythonanywhere-services.com', 3306) ) 

server.start()
local_port = str(server.local_bind_port)
db = 'username$database'
engine = sqlalchemy.create_engine(f'mysql+pymysql://username:password@127.0.0.1:{local_port}/{db}')

print('Engine Created')

df_read = pd.read_sql_table('tablename',engine)
print('Grabbed Table')
writer = ExcelWriter('excelfile.xlsx')
print('writer created')
df_read.to_excel(writer,'8==D') # '8==D' specifies sheet
print('df to excel')
writer.save()
print('saved')
server.stop()
```