# Alembic migration hangs after creating db session

Tags: sqlalchemy, alembic

I'm using [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38001815/4097322) approach to talk to an external database in my alembic migration. I can run `SELECT` statements and read data from the other database, but the alembic migration always ends up hanging after running my statements. I've noticed that removing...

```
Session = sessionmaker(bind=engine)
session = Session()
```

... fixes the issue, but I obviously can't do much without that.

I see no errors, what could be going on?

Comment: I don't think you need a session here; you probably just need to run alembic within the SSL context.

Comment: @snakecharmerb thanks. Can you elaborate more in an answer?

Comment: What I mean is, generally we  don't create a session prior to running alembic upgrades; alembic handles all the db stuff itself, it should only need to know the connection url, which should be in alembic.ini.  So if the migration doesn't work without a session, more information is required (error messages, tracebacks etc)

Comment: @snakecharmerb unfortunately I see no error messages, no tracebacks etc. The migration just hangs, but I see what you're saying... I'm trying to configure the second database using the .ini and env.py files

Comment: @snakecharmerb I created a more specific question for what I think would resolve this issue. Please see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63746113/add-a-second-db-to-alembic-context