# EC2 AMZ Linux - connect to MySQL db from local machine

Tags: mysql, linux, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I am running an Amazon Linux EC2 instance with MySQL v 5.5.54. I am also running a dev version of my application locally. Is there a way to connect to this remote MySQL database from my local machine?

I tried the standard:

```
mysql -h <my dns name> -P 3306 -u myuser -p
```

but my session hangs and nothing gets returned. I am also not seeing any connection attempts in EC2's MySQL logs.

Comment: Is your local machine allowed for inbound in the security group of the EC2 instance?

Comment: @franklinsijo  yes, and I'm also able to ssh into it with `.pem`. Do I need to explicitly allow my ip for MySQL connections?

Comment: Check whether it is allowed for port 3306!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Open port 3306 in the Security Group, with the inbound source set to your local IP address. Comment out the `bind-address` setting in `my.cnf` or change it to something like 0.0.0.0, and restart the MySQL service on the EC2 server. More info on bind-address [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3552680/bind-address-and-mysql-server).

Alternatively, a more secure method would be to use [SSH port forwarding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18373366/mysql-connection-over-ssh-tunnel-how-to-specify-other-mysql-server).