# MySQL SSH "support"

Tags: mysql, linux, ssh

In some official Oracle material I am reading

*"MySQL supports SSH (secure shell)‏ connection to a remote MySQL server.*

*This requires:*

- *An SSH client on the client machine*
- *Port forwarding through an SSH tunnel from the client to the server*
  *A client application on the machine with the SSH client
  When you complete the setup, you have a local port that hosts an SSH connection to MySQL, encrypted using SSH.*"

**Question**

What an application (MySQL) could *"support"* on SSH?
If I using an SSH client, and correctly configure port forwarding, is not the SSH **transparent** for MySQL?  (With other words, MySQL have nothing to ti with this)

I am not a Linux guru, missing I something?

Comment: I could be wrong with this. But in AWS, there are RDS/EC2 instances you can configure as MySQL servers on Private subnets. You can use something like MySQL workbench or the CLI to have any public EC2 instances within your VPC to proxy to the RDS/EC2 that is not publicly available.

Comment: I think it means something like https://support.cloud.engineyard.com/hc/en-us/articles/205408088-Access-Your-Database-Remotely-Through-an-SSH-Tunnel

Comment: It's hard to judge the context, because you haven't linked to the material you're reading. I would guess it might be marketing material that is inexpertly saying "SSH" when they mean that MySQL supports TLS. See https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/encrypted-connections.html

Comment: @BillKarwin: I've added some more context of the quote

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you are talking about SSH Tunneling?  You can use SSH to create your own encrypted connection from a program (client) on one computer to a program (server) on another computer.  And as you mentioned, it works for any client/server programs, not just MySQL/mysqld.

Here is an exiting SO answer that shows you how it's done with MySQL and SSH:

[MySQL connection over SSH tunnel - how to specify other MySQL server?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18373366/mysql-connection-over-ssh-tunnel-how-to-specify-other-mysql-server)

Comment: Yes I meant SSH tunneling. So the text is only a marketing statement...

Comment: Certainly, but it also documents a solution for users that need a secure connection.