# Connection to a remote mysql server when I have to specify a specific port when SSHing

Tags: mysql

So I have a server that I need to be able to do remote mysql calls on. It is running centos 7.

The problem is when I try to run my normal mysql command line call from my own server, running centos 6.8, the call just hangs.

I was wondering if it matters that when I SSH to the server i have to specify a specific port to SSH to.

For example I have to do ssh -p 3400 me@mything.com

I have tried the following:

mysql -h mything.com -u me -pmypass

Thank you for all the help!

Comment: Port 3306 needs to be exposed via firewall-cmd. SSH has nothing to do with this as it’s a completely different service.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18373366/mysql-connection-over-ssh-tunnel-how-to-specify-other-mysql-server