# How to SSH Tunnel from MySQL server

Tags: mysql, ssh, tunnel

I am trying to use an SSH tunnel to provide access *from* my server *to* the MySQL database on my home server, *without* using port forwarding on my home router. In other words, I want to run the MySQL server, *and* establish the SSH tunnel from my home server, and then be able to use the mysql client from the external server. But I keep getting:
    bind: Address already in use

I run the mysql server:
service mysql start

and then describe the ssh tunnel:
    ssh root@hf2.tr8.us -L 3306:127.0.0.1:3306 -N
or:
    ssh root@hf2.tr8.us -L 3306:hf2.tr8.us:3306 -N

Both produce the address in use error. If I create the tunnel first, MySQL refuses to start.

How do I specify the SSH tunnel from the same server that I started MySQL?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [MySQL connection over SSH tunnel - how to specify other MySQL server?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18373366/mysql-connection-over-ssh-tunnel-how-to-specify-other-mysql-server)

Answer (score 0):

What I was looking for was a "reverse" tunnel: -R. This works, *from* the server:

ssh root@hf2.tr8.us -R 3306:127.0.0.1:3306 -N

Comment: Fair enough - that wasn't clear from the question (at least not to me ;)).  Please "accept" your answer.